# select audio file and play it on click button

Tags: android, audio

I created a simple android page that makes you select an audio file, and it works fine and I can select an audio file from my phone but I need to know how to play this audio file by clicking another button,

here is my code for the audio file select:

```
Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
intent_upload.setType("audio/*");
intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent_upload,1);



@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

if(requestCode == 1){

if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

    //the selected audio.
    Uri uri = data.getData(); 
}
}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `MediaPlayer`

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it gives an error in uri

Comment: So the actual issue is to receive the uri not to play the sound?

Comment: yes I want to catch the selected audio and play it

Comment: What does the uri look like? Do you receive any errors?

Comment: I solve it by using getApplicationContext(), instead of this